# Mail Form Validation is not working

Tags: javascript, php, forms

I have this contact form which is sending mails correctly but it doesn't make the server side validation correctly. When I submit an empty form (or with some of the fields completed), it shows the correct field error messages but the form is sent anyway.

Any help would be appreciated.

The form:

```
<form action="php/form-process.php" role="form" id="contactForm">

  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido *" data-error="Por favor, ingrese su nombre">
  <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Teléfono *" data-error="Por favor, ingrese el teléfono">
  <input type="email" name="email" class="email form-control input-lg" id="email" placeholder="Email *" data-error="Por favor, ingrese su email">
  <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="datepicker form-control input-lg" placeholder="Fecha del evento *" data-error="Por favor, ingrese una fecha">
  <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="7" placeholder="Mensaje *" class="form-control input-lg" data-error="Déjenos un mensaje"></textarea>
  <button type="submit" id="submit" class="faa-float animated-hover btn btn-lg btn-default btn-form"></i> ENVIAR</button>

  <div id="msgSubmit" class="h3 text-center hidden"></div> 
  <div class="clearfix"></div>   

</form>
```

The PHP:

```
<?php

$errorMSG = "";

// NAME
if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $errorMSG = "Nombre y Apellido requeridos | ";
} else {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
}

// PHONE
if (empty($_POST["phone"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Teléfono requerido | ";
} else {
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];
}

// EMAIL
if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Email requerido | ";
} else {
    $email = $_POST["email"];
}

// DATE
if (empty($_POST["date"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Fecha requerido | ";
} else {
    $date = $_POST["date"];
}


// MESSAGE
if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $errorMSG .= "Mensaje requerido";
} else {
    $message = $_POST["message"];
}


$EmailTo = "mail@domain.com";
$Subject = "Example subject";

// prepare email body text
$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Telefono: ";
$Body .= $phone;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Fecha: ";
$Body .= $date;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Mensaje: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";


// send email
$success = mail($EmailTo, $Subject, $Body, "From:".$email);



// redirect to success page
if ($success && $errorMSG == ""){
   echo "success";
}else{
    if($errorMSG == ""){
        echo "Something went wrong :(";
    } else {
        echo $errorMSG;
    }
}


?>
```

And the Javascript code

```
$("#contactForm").validator().on("submit", function (event) {
    if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {
        // handle the invalid form...
        formError();
        submitMSG(false, "Verifique el formulario");
    } else {
        // everything looks good!
        event.preventDefault();
        submitForm();
    }
});


function submitForm(){
    // Initiate Variables With Form Content
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var phone = $("#phone").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "php/form-process.php",
        data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&phone=" + phone + "&date=" + date + "&message=" + message,
        success : function(text){
            if (text == "success"){
                formSuccess();
            } else {
                formError();
                submitMSG(false,text);
            }
        }
    });
}

function formSuccess(){
    $("#contactForm")[0].reset();
    submitMSG(true, "Mensaje enviado correctamente!")
}

function formError(){
    $("#contactForm").removeClass().addClass('shake animated').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function(){
        $(this).removeClass();
    });
}

function submitMSG(valid, msg){
    if(valid){
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center tada text-success";
    } else {
        var msgClasses = "h3 text-center text-danger";
    }
    $("#msgSubmit").removeClass().addClass(msgClasses).text(msg);
}
```

Comment: the form is missing

Comment: I just added the form @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @MauroBarrionuevo You should take an array to store the error messages.

Comment: the form inputs don't have a `required` attribute. Please add the  bootstrapvalidator tag if this is what you are using.

Comment: In fact, my original code has the `required` attribute, but in order to test Server Side validation I deleted those.